# Discrete math Group - Isomorphism and Automorphism

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cyclic-groups, exceptional-isomorphisms

Let G be a Cyclic group

Prove or disprove:
A.let $ a,b \in G \quad  $ so the function $ f:G \to  G,f(a^k) = b^k$ is  Automorphism of G(which means G is Isomorphism to herself)

B.let a,b generators of G so the function $ f:G \to  G,f(a^k) = b^k$ is  Automorphism of G(which means G is Isomorphism to herself)

it think A is wrong and B is right
but i don't know t prove or disprove it formally
thanks

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but... In A, is it that $a$ and $b$ can be any elements, and the claim is that this works for all elements? If so, you can disprove it by taking some special element $b$ for which you can easily show it doesn't work ($f$ maps all the elements to the same element, for example).

Answer (score 0):

To disprove the first statement, find a counterexample.

Here's one: take $G = \{0,1,2\}$ with addition modulo $3$.  Define 
$$
f(k) = f(k\cdot 0) = f(1 + \cdots + 1) = 0 + \cdots + 0 = 0
$$
That is, $f(g) = 0$ for all $g \in G$.  Show that $f$ is a homomorphism but not an isomorphism.

To prove the second statement: follow the usual steps.  That is, show that $f$ is a homomorphism that is both one to one (injective) and onto (surjective).

Comment: @Vinay I meant to write "is a homomorphism but not an isomorphism", as you indicated.